# how to select a hash from array of hash? It throws "in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

How to select from the array of hash below to get

> q1={
>                           :question_text => "Have you received your goods?",
>                   :question_export_value => nil,
>                           :question_type => "1",
>                                  :answer => {
>                               :answer_part => nil,
>                             :answer_column => nil,
>                               :answer_text => "Yes",
>                              :answer_other => nil,
>                       :answer_export_value => nil,
>                            :answer_comment => nil
>                   },
>                          :question_score => "0",
>                           :question_code => nil,
>                         :question_number => "1"
>               }

I tried

```
q1 = response[:survey_detail].select { |question| question[:question_number].to_s == "1" }
q1_text = q1[:question_text]  
q1_response = q1[:answer][:answer_text]
```

**but got "in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer** (TypeError)

Here is

> puts response[:survey_detail]

```
{:question_text=>"Please rate the following based on your overall experience:", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"10", :answer=>[{:answer_part=>"Purchasing experience", :answer_column=>"7 - High", :answer_text=>"7 - High", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, {:answer_part=>"Design on the product", :answer_column=>"6", :answer_text=>"6", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, {:answer_part=>"Quality of the product", :answer_column=>"7 - High", :answer_text=>"7 - High", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}], :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"2"}
{:question_text=>"Which best describes your overall experience?", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"2", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"WOW!", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>"2", :question_number=>"4"}
{:question_text=>"In the space below, feel free to share any additional feedback about the aspects above.", :question_type=>"8", :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"3"}
{:question_text=>"My evaluation may be shared with others?", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"1", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"Yes", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"6"}
{:question_text=>"What is the primary reason  ", :question_type=>"8", :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"5"}
{:question_text=>"Have you received your good?", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"1", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"Yes", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"1"}
```

> response[:survey_detail].inspect

```
[{:question_text=>"Please rate the following based on your overall experience:", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"10", :answer=>[{:answer_part=>"Purchasing experience", :answer_column=>"7 - High", :answer_text=>"7 - High", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, {:answer_part=>"Design on the product", :answer_column=>"6", :answer_text=>"6", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, {:answer_part=>"Quality of the product", :answer_column=>"7 - High", :answer_text=>"7 - High", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}], :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"2"}, {:question_text=>"Which best describes your overall experience?", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"2", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"WOW!", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>"2", :question_number=>"4"}, {:question_text=>"In the space below, feel free to share any additional feedback about the aspects above.", :question_type=>"8", :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"3"}, {:question_text=>"My evaluation may be shared with others:", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"1", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"Yes", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"6"}, {:question_text=>"What is the primary reason for the score you just gave us?", :question_type=>"8", :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"5"}, {:question_text=>"Have you received your shirt or product as part  ?", :question_export_value=>nil, :question_type=>"1", :answer=>{:answer_part=>nil, :answer_column=>nil, :answer_text=>"Yes", :answer_other=>nil, :answer_export_value=>nil, :answer_comment=>nil}, :question_score=>"0", :question_code=>nil, :question_number=>"1"}]
```

Comment: Hi @EricDuminil. Again thanks for you help. Today I found out there are two scenarios:   :survey_detail => {:question_number => "1"} and  :survey_detail => {[:question_number => "1"]}. If there are more than one question answered, it returns an Array of Hash.  If there's only one question answered, it returns a Hash.  So the *find* solution only works with Array of Hash. Could you let me know how to choose if it returns a Hash?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Replace `select` with `find`, and you're good to go.

With `select`, you get back an Array of elements which satisfy the condition in the block, even if it only is an Array with 1 element.

```
(1..10).select{|i| i>3 && i<5}
#=> [4]
```

With `find`, you get back the first element which satisfies the condition in the block.

```
(1..10).find{|i| i>3 && i<5}
#=> 4
```

So :

```
q1 = response[:survey_detail].find{|question| question[:question_number].to_s == "1" }
q1_text = q1[:question_text]
q1_response =q1[:answer][:answer_text]
#=> "Yes"
```

Comment: Is response[:survey_detail] an array or a hash?

Comment: Yes. it returns Array.

Comment: q1 = response[:survey_detail].find{|question| question[:question_number] == "1" }
  puts q1.class
  exit . Now q1 becomes a Hash. How can I make sure q1 to be an array? I need to do q1_question = q1[:question_text], since q1 is now a Hash, it erros out.

Comment: as you said, @eric if use select, q1 is an array, if use find, q1 is a hash

Comment: Could you please update your question and post a complete and correct definition of your `response`, or at least `response[:survey_detail]`? `q1_question` is a Hash, and if it contains `:question_text`, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: q1 = response[:survey_detail].find{|question| question[:question_number] == "1"}  #return a Hash
  q1_recommend = q1[:question_text]  #error out here `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: q1 = response[:survey_detail].find{|question| question[:question_number] == "1"}

Answer (score 0):

Does `q1 = response[:survey_detail][0]` or `q1 = response[:survey_detail].each` not work? `response[:survey_detail]` is an array so any Array methods should work on it. The fact that the is inside of a Hash is not really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`response[:survey_detail]` return a hash if there's only 1 question. 
`response[:survey_detail]` return an array of hash if there's more than 1 question.

The business logic is that if quesion1.answer="No" then the survey exit.

So, my problem becomes when `response[:survey_detail]` return only 1 hash, `response[:survey_detail].find...` or `response[:survey_detail].select { |question| question[:question_number].to_s == "1" }[0]` won't operate on hash.

Thus it throws "`in`[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`

This error basically means I'm using a function available to an Array on a Hash.

I did `is_a?(Hash)` to test response[:survey_detail] then divide it into two scenarios,hash or array.